# MonoTouch: Xcode 4.3.2 - Compatible version

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

What version of MonoTouch is needed to use the newly release Xcode 4.3.2 It seems xCode is now using a different deployment model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 support was introduced in [MonoTouch 5.2.5](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.2#MonoTouch_5.2.5).